# Como comparar Arrays?

Tags: java, arraylist

Necessito fazer a comparação de diversos `Array`, para pesquisar valores iguais...

**Regras de Negócio**

- Poderá existir array com quantidades de valores maiores que o outro.
- Poderá existir Array com a mesma quantidade de valores.

**Exemplo:**

```
A = [1,2,4,6,7,8, 10,12,13,17,18,21,23,24,25];
B = [1,2,4,6,7,8, 10,12,13,17,18,21,23,24,25]; // é igual ao array A.
C = [1,2,5,6,7,8, 9,12,13,17,18,21,23,24,25]; // é igual Array C.
```

o `Array B` é igual ao `Array A`, porém o `Array C` possuem valores diferentes...

Comment: entendi, mas comparar e saber se são iguais apenas usando o nome da lista nao tem como né?  elas ja estariam ordenadas..

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar **algoritmos de ordenação** e **técnicas de interseção e União**, siga estes passos em sua ordem:

- Ordenar os `Array`
- Verificar a Interseção dos `Array`
- Unir a Interseção dos mesmos.

**Da Ordenação:**

> Você pode utilizar um algoritmo existente denominado `MergeSort`, onde ele utiliza a estratégia **"dividir-para-conquista"** e a complexidade do mesmo no melhor e pior caso é `O(n log n)`.

**Exemplo animado do funcionamento do** `MergeSort`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Algoritmo:**

```
public class WikiMerge<T extends Comparable<T>>{
     /**
    * Método que recebe um array de inteiros e dois inteiros referentes ao início e ao fim
    * da ordenação desse array, o que nos garante o poder de escolher uma faixa do array
    * para ser ordenado.
    *
    * @param array
    * @param indiceInicio
    * @param indiceFim
    */
    public void ordena(T[] array, int indiceInicio, int indiceFim) {

        // Condicional que verifica a validade dos parâmetros passados.
        if (array != null && indiceInicio < indiceFim && indiceInicio >= 0 &&
         indiceFim < array.length && array.length != 0) {
            int meio = ((indiceFim + indiceInicio) / 2);

            ordena(array, indiceInicio, meio);
            ordena(array, meio + 1, indiceFim);

            merge(array, indiceInicio, meio, indiceFim);
        }

    }

    /**
    * O merge consiste na junção de duas listas já ordenadas.
    * Usa um array auxiliar.
    *
    * @param array
    * @param indiceInicio
    * @param meio
    * @param indiceFim
    */
    public void merge(T[] array, int indiceInicio, int meio, int indiceFim) {

        T[] auxiliar =(T[]) new Comparable[array.length];
        //Copiando o trecho da lista que vai ser ordenada
        for (int i = indiceInicio; i <= indiceFim; i++) {
            auxiliar[i] = array[i];
        }

        //Índices auxiliares
        int i = indiceInicio;
        int j = meio + 1;
        int k = indiceInicio;

        //Junção das listas ordenadas
        while (i <= meio && j <= indiceFim) {
            if (auxiliar[i].compareTo(auxiliar[j]) < 0) {
                array[k] = auxiliar[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                array[k] = auxiliar[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        //Append de itens que não foram usados na Junção
        while (i <= meio) {
            array[k] = auxiliar[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        //Append de itens que não foram usados na Junção
        while (j <= indiceFim) {
            array[k] = auxiliar[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Da Interseção**

> Você pode utilizar diversas técnicas (algoritmos) existente para fazer a interseção e união, onde a complexidade do mesmo é de `O(n+m)` que é igual a `O(n)`.

**Algoritmo de uma das Técnicas de Interseção e União:**

```
// Um programa em Java para imprimir união e interseção
/// de duas matrizes não classificadas
import java.util.Arrays; 

class UnionAndIntersection  
{ 
    //Imprime a união de arr1 [0..m-1] e arr2 [0..n-1]
    void printUnion(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n)  
    { 
        // Antes de encontrar a união, certifique-se de que arr1 [0..m-1]
        // é menor
        if (m > n)  
        { 
            int tempp[] = arr1; 
            arr1 = arr2; 
            arr2 = tempp; 

            int temp = m; 
            m = n; 
            n = temp; 
        } 

        // Agora arr1 [] é menor
        // Ordenar o primeiro array e imprime seus elementos (esses dois
        // as etapas podem ser trocadas, pois a ordem na saída não é importante)
        Arrays.sort(arr1); 
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
            System.out.print(arr1[i] + " "); 

        // Pesquisar todos os elementos da matriz maior em uma matriz menor
        // e imprime o elemento se não for encontrado
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        { 
            if (binarySearch(arr1, 0, m - 1, arr2[i]) == -1) 
                System.out.print(arr2[i] + " "); 
        } 
    } 

    // Imprime intersecção de arr1 [0..m-1] e arr2 [0..n-1] 
    void printIntersection(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n)  
    { 

        // Antes de encontrar o cruzamento, certifique-se de que arr1 [0..m-1]
        // é menor
        if (m > n)  
        { 
            int tempp[] = arr1; 
            arr1 = arr2; 
            arr2 = tempp; 

            int temp = m; 
            m = n; 
            n = temp; 
        } 

        // Agora arr1 [] é menor
        // Classificar array menor arr1 [0..m-1]
        Arrays.sort(arr1); 

        // Pesquisar todos os elementos da matriz maior em uma matriz menor
        // e imprima o elemento se encontrado
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        { 
            if (binarySearch(arr1, 0, m - 1, arr2[i]) != -1)  
                System.out.print(arr2[i] + " "); 
        } 
    } 

    // Uma função de pesquisa binária recursiva. Retorna a localização de x em
    // dado array arr [l..r] está presente, caso contrário -1
    int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)  
    { 
        if (r >= l)  
        { 
            int mid = l + (r - l) / 2; 

            // Se o elemento estiver presente no meio
            if (arr[mid] == x) 
                return mid; 


            // Se o elemento for menor que o meio, então ele só pode
            // estar presente no subarray esquerdo
            if (arr[mid] > x) 
                return binarySearch(arr, l, mid - 1, x); 

            // Else o elemento só pode estar presente no subarray direito 
            return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, r, x); 
        } 

        // Nós chegamos aqui quando o elemento não está presente no array
        return -1; 
    } 

    // Programa do driver para testar as funções acima
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    { 
        UnionAndIntersection u_i = new UnionAndIntersection(); 
        int arr1[] = {7, 1, 5, 2, 3, 6}; 
        int arr2[] = {3, 8, 6, 20, 7}; 
        int m = arr1.length; 
        int n = arr2.length; 
        System.out.println("Union of two arrays is "); 
        u_i.printUnion(arr1, arr2, m, n); 
        System.out.println(""); 
        System.out.println("Intersection of two arrays is "); 
        u_i.printIntersection(arr1, arr2, m, n); 
    } 
}
```

**Note:**

> - [Acesse este link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) para saber mais sobre o `MergeSort`.
> - [Acesse este link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-union-and-intersection-of-two-unsorted-arrays/) para saber mais sobre as técnicas de interseção e união.

**PS:**

> - Existem diversos outros algoritmos para ordenar, então sugiro que [acesse este link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o) para saber mais sobre os mesmos.
> - Leia atentamente o link das técnicas de interseção e união, pois existem diversas técnicas para o qual tem sua utilidade.

Comment: entendi, mas comparar e saber se são iguais apenas usando o nome da lista nao tem como né?  elas ja estariam ordenadas..

Comment: Como assim **"usando o nome da lista"** ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a api de Streams para filtrar a interseção entre listas.

```
List<Integer> collect = lista1.stream()
                .filter(lista2::contains)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Se sua intenção é meramente fazer uma comparação atômica, você pode usar o método [allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate) com predicado de comparação simples.

```
Boolean equality = (IntStream.range(0,lista1.size())
                    .allMatch(i -> lista1.get(i) == lista2.get(i)));
```

Se você precisar ordenar em alguma lista antes de comparar os itens, pode simplesmente usar método [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) de alguma lista passando um [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
lista2.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Agora se você precisar filtrar os itens por uma relação de intersecção, a resposta do Bruno é mais bacana.

Comment: Seria apenas comparar se array são iguais, elas já estariam ordenadas, preciso saber se array A é igual a B.

Comment: Segue um exemplo no Ideone: https://ideone.com/1k2xZI